# How to switch between two QGraphicsView inside a QWidget

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget

I have two different views to display inside a QWidget window. Each view has a separate QGraphicsScene.
I want to toggle between the two views on button click.

This is my current implementation:

```
    void toggleUi(bool type){
    QGraphicsView* currentView;
    
    if(bool){
     currentView = getFirstView(); // returns QGraphicsView of first type
    }
    else{
     currentView = getSecondView(); // returns QGraphicsView of second type
    }

    QLayout* layout = widget->layout ();
    if (layout != 0)
    {
    QLayoutItem *item;
    while ((item = layout->takeAt(0)) != 0)
        layout->removeItem (item);
    delete layout;
    }

   QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
   layout->addWidget(currentView);
}
```

Issue: Both views are displayed over one another on toggle, even after deleting the layout and adding a new one.
Both views are rendered fine without toggle.
Is there a better/another way to do it?

Comment: Don't mess around with layouts. Also, removing a widget from a layout doesn't hide it, it only makes that widget *not more managed by the layout*. Use QStackedWidget.

Comment: Got your point. Is there a way to toggle viwes without the QStackedWidget using just QWidget?

Comment: Why don't you want to use QStackedWidget?

Comment: @Tim Got clarity by seeing your posted snippet, QStackedWidget is better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`QStackedWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstackedwidget.html)! Use the `addWidget` function to add widgets:

```cpp
QStackedWidget *stackedWidget = new QStackedWidget(this);
stackedWidget->addWidget(getFirstView());
stackedWidget->addWidget(getSecoundView());

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
layout->addWidget(stackedWidget);
setLayout(layout);
```

Here's how to switch between the widgets:

```cpp
void toggleUi(bool type){
    if(condition)
        stackedWidget->setCurrentindex(0)
    else
        stackedWidget->setCurrentindex(1)
```

I hope it helps!